# mod-security not blocking POST request

Tags: mod-security

I have a mod-security compiled from source and installed on Ubuntu Server 12.04, Apache 2.2.22.  I loaded the OWASP core rule set, and I can see them getting triggered on the log file /var/log/apache2/error.log with a simple POST request with

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

However, I am still getting the response from the php page.

Here is my modsecurity.conf

```
# -- Rule engine initialization ----------------------------------------------

# Enable ModSecurity, attaching it to every transaction. Use detection
# only to start with, because that minimises the chances of post-installation
# disruption.
#
#SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
SecRuleEngine On


# -- Request body handling ---------------------------------------------------

# Allow ModSecurity to access request bodies. If you don't, ModSecurity
# won't be able to see any POST parameters, which opens a large security
# hole for attackers to exploit.
#
SecRequestBodyAccess On


# Enable XML request body parser.
# Initiate XML Processor in case of xml content-type
#
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" \
     "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"


# Maximum request body size we will accept for buffering. If you support
# file uploads then the value given on the first line has to be as large
# as the largest file you are willing to accept. The second value refers
# to the size of data, with files excluded. You want to keep that value as
# low as practical.
#
SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072

# Store up to 128 KB of request body data in memory. When the multipart
# parser reachers this limit, it will start using your hard disk for
# storage. That is slow, but unavoidable.
#
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072

# What do do if the request body size is above our configured limit.
# Keep in mind that this setting will automatically be set to ProcessPartial
# when SecRuleEngine is set to DetectionOnly mode in order to minimize
# disruptions when initially deploying ModSecurity.
#
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject

# Verify that we've correctly processed the request body.
# As a rule of thumb, when failing to process a request body
# you should reject the request (when deployed in blocking mode)
# or log a high-severity alert (when deployed in detection-only mode).
#
SecRule REQBODY_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200001', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2"

# By default be strict with what we accept in the multipart/form-data
# request body. If the rule below proves to be too strict for your
# environment consider changing it to detection-only. You are encouraged
# _not_ to remove it altogether.
```

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_security.load

```
LoadFile /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
LoadFile /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so

LoadModule security2_module /usr/local/lib/mod_security2.so
<IfModule !mod_security2.c>
error_mod_security_is_not_loaded
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security2.c>
Include "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/*.conf"
Include /etc/modsecurity/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

/var/log/modsec_audit.log (snippet)

```
Message: Warning. Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf"] [line "312"] [id "960012"] [rev "1"] [msg "POST request missing Content-Length Header."] [data "0"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ"] [tag "CAPEC-272"]
Message: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "31"] [id "960032"] [rev "2"] [msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "POST"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"]
Message: Warning. Match of "rx ^%{tx.allowed_request_content_type}$" against "TX:0" required. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "64"] [id "960010"] [rev "2"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"] [data "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/ENCODING_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-20"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/EE2"] [tag "PCI/12.1"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "(?i:([\\s'\"`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98\\(\\)]*?)\\b([\\d\\w]++)([\\s'\"`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98\\(\\)]*?)(?:(?:=|<=>|r?like|sounds\\s+like|regexp)([\\s'\"`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98\\(\\)]*?)\\2\\b|(?:!=|<=|>=|<>|<|>|\\^|is\\s+not ..." at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "77"] [id "950901"] [rev "2"] [msg "SQL Injection Attack: SQL Tautology Detected."] [data "Matched Data: script>alert found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-19"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "([\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\:\\;\"\\'\\\xc2\xb4\\\xe2\x80\x99\\\xe2\x80\x98\\`\\<\\>].*?){4,}" at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "159"] [id "981173"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"] [data "Matched Data: < found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "\\balert\\b\\W*?\\(" at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"] [line "163"] [id "958052"] [rev "2"] [msg "Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Attack"] [data "Matched Data: alert( found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "8"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A2"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "\\< ?script\\b" at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"] [line "211"] [id "958051"] [rev "2"] [msg "Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Attack"] [data "Matched Data: <script found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "8"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A2"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "<(a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|audioscope|b|base|basefront|bdo|bgsound|big|blackface|blink|blockquote|body|bq|br|button|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|comment|dd|del|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|fn|font|form|frame|frameset|h1|head|h ..." at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"] [line "301"] [id "973300"] [rev "2"] [msg "Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler"] [data "Matched Data: <script> found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "8"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A2"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "(fromcharcode|alert|eval)\\s*\\(" at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"] [line "391"] [id "973307"] [rev "2"] [msg "XSS Attack Detected"] [data "Matched Data: alert( found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "8"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A2"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "(?i:<script.*?>)" at ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"] [line "472"] [id "973331"] [rev "2"] [msg "IE XSS Filters - Attack Detected."] [data "Matched Data: <script> found within ARGS_NAMES:<script>alert(1)</script>: <script>alert(1)</script>"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "8"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A2"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"]
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "37"] [id "981204"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 33, SQLi=6, XSS=25): IE XSS Filters - Attack Detected."]
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1410989836928471 21584 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1410989836928471 21584; combined=9852, p1=2043, p2=6830, p3=7, p4=532, p5=439, sr=172, sw=1, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.5 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9.
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--741c3b08-Z--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually told mod security what to do, i.e. the default rule:

Try this:
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,pass,log,auditlog"

Which sets anomaly mode.

Comment: I remember this is what i did to fix this issue.